# Codility voracious fish are moving along a river, solution in C#

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, array, stack

This is the task's description. My code gets 100% task score. Is it good code yet? (I think I'm getting a lot better, since I started solving this codility's exercises and posting here, but I always get important things to improve -which help me A LOT!- from reviewers)

> ***N voracious fish are moving along a river. Calculate how many fish are alive.***

---

> You are given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of
>   N integers. Arrays A and B represent N voracious fish in a river,
>   ordered downstream along the flow of the river.
>
> The fish are numbered from 0 to N − 1. If P and Q are two fish and P <
>   Q, then fish P is initially upstream of fish Q. Initially, each fish
>   has a unique position.
>
> Fish number P is represented by A[P] and B[P]. Array A contains the
>   sizes of the fish. All its elements are unique. Array B contains the
>   directions of the fish. It contains only 0s and/or 1s, where:
>
> 0 represents a fish flowing upstream, 1 represents a fish flowing
>   downstream. If two fish move in opposite directions and there are no
>   other (living) fish between them, they will eventually meet each
>   other. Then only one fish can stay alive − the larger fish eats the
>   smaller one. More precisely, we say that two fish P and Q meet each
>   other when P < Q, B[P] = 1 and B[Q] = 0, and there are no living fish
>   between them. After they meet:
>
> If A[P] > A[Q] then P eats Q, and P will still be flowing downstream.
>   If A[Q] > A[P] then Q eats P, and Q will still be flowing upstream. We
>   assume that all the fish are flowing at the same speed. That is, fish
>   moving in the same direction never meet. The goal is to calculate the
>   number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, consider arrays A and B such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4    B[0] = 0
> A[1] = 3    B[1] = 1
> A[2] = 2    B[2] = 0
> A[3] = 1    B[3] = 0
> A[4] = 5    B[4] = 0
> ```
>
> Initially all the fish are alive and all except fish number 1 are
>   moving upstream. Fish number 1 meets fish number 2 and eats it, then
>   it meets fish number 3 and eats it too. Finally, it meets fish number
>   4 and is eaten by it. The remaining two fish, number 0 and 4, never
>   meet and therefore stay alive.
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A, int[] B); }
> ```
>
> that, given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of N
>   integers, returns the number of fish that will stay alive.
>
> For example, given the arrays shown above, the function should return
>   2, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000]; each element of
>   array B is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1;
>   the elements of A are all distinct.
>
> Complexity:
>
> Expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B)
    {
        const int UpstreamFloater = 0;
        const int DownstreamFloater = 1;

        Stack<int> downstreamersStack = new Stack<int>();

        int topStackDownstreamer;

        int aliveFishesCounter = 0;

        for (int fish = 0; fish < B.Length; fish++)
        {
            if (downstreamersStack.Count == 0 && B[fish] == UpstreamFloater)
            {
                aliveFishesCounter++;
            }
            else if (B[fish] == DownstreamFloater)
            {
                downstreamersStack.Push(fish);
            }
            else if (B[fish] == UpstreamFloater)
            {
                topStackDownstreamer = downstreamersStack.Peek();
                while (downstreamersStack.Count > 0 && A[fish] > A[topStackDownstreamer])
                {
                    downstreamersStack.Pop();
                    if (downstreamersStack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        topStackDownstreamer = downstreamersStack.Peek();
                    }
                }
                if (downstreamersStack.Count == 0)
                {
                    aliveFishesCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        aliveFishesCounter += downstreamersStack.Count;
        return aliveFishesCounter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is good. There are a couple bits you could change, sure. Some of them boil down to personal preferences.

Give the arrays more useful names:

```
public int solution(int[] size, int[] direction)
```

Declare `topStackDownstreamer` when you need it. Keeping the scope of a variable minimal gives you less things to remember. What is `topStackDownstreamer`? How is it used? What was it's value when we assign a new one? Should we do something with the old value first?

But you might as well not need `topStackDownstreamer` at all.

As you use `if` and two `else if` your code looks like it is missing something - the last `else`. I'd recommend using one `if` and `else` for clarity. You could also restructure the stack looping a little bit and check for stacksize=0 only once:

```
        if (direction[fish] == DownstreamFloater)
        {
            downstreamersStack.Push(fish);
        }
        else // must be UpstreamFloater
        {
            while (downstreamersStack.Count > 0)
            {
                if(size[fish] > size[downstreamersStack.Peek()])
                {
                    downstreamersStack.Pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (downstreamersStack.Count == 0)
            {
                aliveFishesCounter++;
            }
        }
```

Another little bit - you could return without storing the added variables:

```
return aliveFishesCounter + downstreamersStack.Count;
```

The last bit - maybe you could use shorter identifiers. e.g. `direction[fish] == DownstreamFloater` would look better if it was `direction[fish] == Downstream`. Another example `aliveFishesCounter` could be `survivors`.